# Python--adding list into dict (beginner)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm very new to programming (taking my first class in it now), so bear with me for format issues and misunderstandings, or missing easy fixes.

I have a dict with tweet data: 'user' as keys and then 'text' as their values. My goal here is to find the tweets where they are replying to another user, signified by starting with the @ symbol, and then make a new dict that contains the author's user and the users of everyone he replied to. That's the fairly simple if statement I have below. I was also able to use the split function to isolate the username of the person they are replying to (the function takes all the text between the @ symbol and the next space after it).

```
st='@'
en=' '
task1dict={}
for t in a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n:
    if t['text'][0]=='@':
        user=t['user']
        repliedto=t['text'].split(st)[-1].split(en)[0]
        task1dict[user]=[repliedto]
```

Username1 replied to username2. Username2 replied to both username3 and username5.

I am trying to create a dict (caled tweets1) that reads something like:

```
'user':'repliedto'
username1:[username2]
username2:[username3, username5]
```

etc.

Is there a better way to isolate the usernames, and then put them into a new dict? Here's a 2 entry sample of the tweet data:

```
{"user":"datageek88","text":"@sundevil1992 good question! @joeclarknet Is this on the exam?"},
{"user":"joeclarkphd","text":"Exam questions will be answered in due time @sundevil1992"}
```

I am now able to add them to a dict, but it would only save one 'repliedto' for each 'user', so instead of showing username2 have replied to both 3 and 5, it just shows the latest one, 5:

```
{'username1': ['username2'],
'username2': ['username5']}
```

Again, if I'm making a serious no-no anywhere in here, I apologize, and please show me what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the last line to

```
 task1dict.setdefault(user, [])
 task1dict[user].append (repliedto)
```

You were overwriting the users replied to array each time you edited it. The setdefault method will set the dict to have a empty list if it doesn't already exist. Then just append to the list.

EDIT: same code using a set for uniqueness.

```
 task1dict.setdefault(user, set())
 task1dict[user].add (repliedto)
```

For a set you add an element to the set. Whereas a list you append to the list

Comment: Awesome! It did almost exactly what I wanted it to. However, is there any easy way to make it ignore duplicates? For example, username2 replied to username5 on 2 different times, so it's showing username5 twice in task1dict.

Comment: Yes. Instead of using a list. Use a set. A set is like list but it cannot contain duplicates. I'll modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

I might do it like this.  Use the following regular expression to identify all usernames.

```
r"@([^\s]*)"
```

It means look for the `@` symbol, and then return all characters that aren't a space. A `defaultdict` is a simply a dictionary that returns a default value if they key isn't found.  In this case, I specify an empty `set` as the return type in the event that we are adding a new key.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
tweets = [{"user":"datageek88","text":"@sundevil1992 good question! @joeclarknet Is this on the exam?"},
{"user":"joeclarkphd","text":"Exam questions will be answered in due time @sundevil1992"}]

from_to = defaultdict(set)
for tweet in tweets:
    if "@" in tweet['text']:
        user = tweet['user']
        for replied_to in re.findall(r"@([^\s]*)", tweet['text']):
            from_to[user].add(replied_to)

print from_to
```

## Output

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'joeclarkphd': ['sundevil1992'], 
'datageek88': ['sundevil1992', 'joeclarknet']})
```